# convert the systemdate in iso 8601 format in perl

Tags: perl, iso8601

I want the system date to be converted to ISO 8601 format.
code:

```
my $now = time();
my $tz = strftime("%z", localtime($now));
$tz =~ s/(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1:$2/;
print "Time zone *******-> \"$tz\"\n";
# ISO8601
my $currentDate =  strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", localtime($now)) . $tz;
print "Current date *******-> \"$currentDate\"\n";
```

Current output is:

```
Time zone *******-> "-04:00"
Current date *******-> "2014-06-03T03:46:07-04:00"
```

I want the current date to be in format "2014-07-02T10:48:07.124Z", So that I can compute the difference between the two.

Comment: what module provides the `strftime` function?

Comment: @choroba as a sub, not a method, usually it's POSIX

Comment: Naturally, others have already solved this: [`DateTime::Format::ISO8601`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DateTime-Format-ISO8601/lib/DateTime/Format/ISO8601.pod)

Answer (score 16):

You should use [`gmtime()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html) instead of [`localtime()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) to get the broken-down time values in UTC.

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $now = time();
print strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ', gmtime($now)), "\n";
```

output:

```
2014-06-04T10:17:17Z
```

Comment: You might want to use `'%FT%TZ'` as the string. Same format, but shorter, and explicitly selecting the ISO 8601 date format (`%F`) and ISO 8601 time format (`%T`) instead of engineering ISO 8601.

Answer (score 15):

Perl's `DateTime` package ([on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime)) can produce ISO8601 dates for you very easily, but, with one caveat.

The string returned by `DateTime` will be in UTC, but, without a timezone specifier. This SHOULD be fine, because according to the ISO8601 spec, if no timezone is specified, then UTC should be assumed. However, not all parsers obey the spec perfectly. To make my dates more robust I append a `Z` to the end of the string I get from `DateTime`, so this is the code I recommend:

```
use DateTime;
my $now = DateTime->now()->iso8601().'Z';
```

Comment: `DateTime->now()->format_cldr("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")` is a more dynamic (albeit verbose) way of appending the offset.  In this case, `+00:00` will be appended instead of `Z`, but that still suffices for ISO 8601.

Comment: @bart-b Do you have a reference to the ISO8601 spec saying that UTC should be assumed? I have only seeing documentation saying that local time is assumed if the Z is missing.

Comment: `DateTime->now->rfc3339` is better here, since it already supports adding in the timezone.

Answer (score 7):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aPiece) and [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aSeconds) have been included as a standard part of Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

my $time = localtime;
say $time->datetime; # Time in ISO8601 format
say $time->tzoffset; # Time zone offset in seconds

# But tzoffset actually returns a Time::Seconds object
say $time->tzoffset->hours; # Time zone offset in hours (for example)
```

Comment: This script is not running on perl v5.8.8, for this Perl v5.10.0 required-

Comment: @DaveCross Time::Piece *continues* to be a part of Core Perl, and using modern features is not problematic-- especially since hardcoding line endings is far worse than enforcing a moderately recent version of Perl.

Comment: @VectorGorgoth: I am well aware that Time::Piece is still part of core Perl. I'm not sure why you think you need to remind me.

Answer (score -2):

This uses just standard packages:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
  
sub iso8601
{
  my ($s, $f) = split (/\./, gettimeofday);
  strftime ('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.'.$f.'%z', localtime ($s))
}

print iso8601, "\n";
```